# How can I determine the SATA controller version on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd, sata, slax

I have recently bought the [ASUS N550JV-DB71](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834231098CVF) and I am planning on replacing the Bluray Drive with an SSD. Is there any way that I can confirm whether the BD Drive is connected via a SATA 2 or a SATA 3 port?
It would help in determining where to connect the SSD.

I have come across [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/458907/246756) which instructs how it may be done on Ubuntu but would like a solution for Windows.
If one doesn't exist, would it be possible to determine this information using an Ubuntu or SLAX live disc?

Comment: Why does it matter?  SATA3 is backwards compatible with SATA2.  Eject the Blu-ray drive and insert the SSD of the same form factor.

Comment: @Ramhound In the even that there is only one SATA3 controller, I'd plug the SSD there and the HDD in the other one.

Comment: Your laptop isn't going to have two SATA ports....Besides you said you were replacing one with the other stop changing the variables to the question

Comment: SSDs got really fast. When connected over SATA III, the best provide throughput around 560 MB/s, which is close to the 600 MB/s theoretical limit. SATA II has theoretical limit of 300 MB/s, which would be a bottleneck for a modern SSD. http://www.fastestssd.com/featured/ssd-rankings-the-fastest-solid-state-drives/

Comment: How do you get to 600 MB/s theoretical limit? Signal speed on the lines is 6Gbit/sec. But that includes overhead, not maximum effective data transfer.

Comment: @Hennes Actually, he isn't far off... 6Gbit/s is roughly 750MByte/s... bits does equal bytes.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A program called HWiNFO can display the interfaces of your system's HDDs (hard disk drives) and ODDs (optical disk drives). 
You can get it here: http://www.hwinfo.com/download.php

There is even a portable application so you don't have to install it.

Look in the "drives" box to see the matching interface.

[image]

**Edit, (from different user, Rasmus)**: This shows the bandwidth for the hard drive/SSD/hybrid disk installed! Not the motherboard itself. You can see the description under this program; "Drives", *sub-catagory*: "Interface" - "Model". Use a program like SiSoftware Sandra (freeware/trial) or PC Wizard (freeware) to check the actual support of your SATA interface. SATA 600 (MBs) (3/III) or 300 (MBs) (2/II).

If you have a SATA II hard drive installed in your computer, this program (HWiNFO) will show "Interface" --> 3 Gb/s (300 MBs) under the category "Drives", but if you use the program "SiSoftware Sandra", you will see under "Mainboard" that the "Maximum SATA Mode" under "Disk Controller" is "SATA600" or SATA III / 6Gb/s (600MBs). If you use PC Wizard 2014 (example version), you will see that, under "Drives" --> "Number of Disk Controllers",
the bandwidth will be "6 Gb/s", but if you click on "Number of Hard Disk",
you will see that the "Serial ATA Version" is "2.0 - (SATA-300)" *for the hard drive*.

[image]

This is the situation on my laptop, where I have an old 2.5-inch 320 GB hard drive installed, which has SATA II (3 Gbs/300 MBs); but the software
(when you look under the right section) shows that the disk controller for the computer supports SATA III (6 Gbs/600 MBs).

Comment: Portable version was quick and easy to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 31):

In HWINFO, navigate in the device tree to Bus > PCI Bus #0.  Under PCI Bus #0, click on the SATA AHCI Controller device.  Details about this device will be displayed in the right pane.  Scroll through this pane and you will find a heading "SATA Host Controller" with the Interface Speed Supported as follows:

[image: interface speed supported]

Comment: Nice finding it save me an installation of heavy weight "SiSoftware Sandra"

Answer (score 1):

As long as you haven't (sorry if this statement is nauseatingly self-evident) previously swapped out your laptop's hard drive and you're still using the original, maybe this website will help: http://www.drivesolutions.com/index.shtml. I have an old VAIO, and spent about 15 minutes looking up in Device Manager what HDD was factory installed (Fujitsu XXXXXX), and then punched it into google to try to find if any sellers of these fossils posted the Gb/s SATA speed to dx what I should buy. Just scroll down and on the left side there's an option to check your upgrades by model. You could also use http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/advisor which won't tell you what SATA you have, but will tell you what's compatible. And their prices are pretty good, too, if you compare them with the drivesolutions website I posted above.

I read minutes ago on a web browser I shut down (so I can't source it), that as long as your old HD has fewer Gb/s than your new one, as long as it's compatible, the only downside would be failing to take advantage of how fast it COULD run. It will still run. It'll just use 1 or 3 ports instead of, say, 6. Hopefully this helps. I'm learning all this stuff new now, so don't take my word as expert. I'm excited to be doing this all myself in the coming days when I buy my parts. Feel free to reach out to experts in customer service on these parts distribution centers, too, as a prospective buyer. Their guys are much more knowledgeable and might have more thorough (or more correct) information than that which I've picked up on echoes in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the [hwinfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/download.php) application what’s indicated in the drives section is the SATA Interface version used by your existing HDD not the SATA Interface version supported by your motherboard. If you need to find out whether you will be able to get the best out of your new 6Gb/s SSD is to check if your SATA Host controller supports SATA III - 6Gb/s.

To check that click on save the report from the hwinfo application and in the generated html file check for the SATA Host Controller section. Under this section you should be able to see the Interface Speed Supported field.
For more have a have a look at my answer on Quora [here](http://qr.ae/TU1OnJ).

Comment: @Run5k That's fair. I have addressed your concern. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: your answer on quora is deleted. Also it's better to quote, so that in future, if the link no longer works you have more information. This answer as of now isn't very useful.