# Need an SSD compatible with Sony VAIO VPCEH3AEN

Tags: laptop, ssd, sony-vaio

I have to replace the existing HDD in my Sony VAIO VPCEH3AEN with an SSD. A scan with Crucial Scanner by crucial.com suggests, but naturally, **Crucial BX300 480 GB SATA SSD** and it is a confirmed compatible drive.

Secondly, another website shows **Samsung EVO 850 500GB SATA-III SSD** as compatible with the laptop.

To be very brief, the Crucial SSD has significantly faster `sequential` reads and writes, but the Samsung SSD has significantly faster `random` reads and writes.

I would like to go for Samsung SSD that suits my usage pattern better I but could not confirm its compatibility by Googling. Contacted manufacturer for compatibility, and they refused to reply. Note that but drives have 7mm height and 9.5 mm connector that will fit-in the laptop.

My question, does the Sony VAIO VPCEH3AEN laptop support SATA-III SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any 2.5-inch SSD will work in that laptop. According to [SanDisk](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i%2C-sata-ii-and-sata-iii), SATA versions are backwards-compatible. This means that you can put a SATA-III drive into a SATA-II port and it will work, but you would not get the higher sequential read/write speeds of SATA-III. Regardless of which SATA version your motherboard supports, the SSD will still give you an enormous boost in random read/write speeds as opposed to using a hard drive. However, **SATA II will limit the sequential read/write speeds of the [EVO 850](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P73B1E4) from 540MB/s and 520MB/s to 285MB/s and 275MB/s.**

Unfortunately, I do not own that laptop and cannot find the SATA version online. However, the *second* answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/633839/how-can-i-determine-the-sata-controller-version-on-windows) provides a way to do this if you run Windows.

Finally, make sure that the model you get is a 2.5-inch one. Almost every SSD comes in 2.5in, 3.5in, and M.2 formats but any 2.5in one you find will work in your laptop.

Comment: @user854774: Your are right. Fitting the drive was not the issue for me. It was SATA vs SATA-III issue. Even I could not find online which SATA port does the laptop  has. Your reply has given good deal of hope.